# How to parse JSON feed from a d8 into another d8 site using Feeds Migrate Module

Tags: migrations, feeds

This is the JSON output from a view using REST export

```
    [
  {
    "spotlight-title": "Spotlight 3",
    "spotlight-body": "<p>This is spotlight 3</p>"
  },
  {
    "spotlight-title": "Spotlight 2",
    "spotlight-body": "<p>this is spotlight 2</p>"
  },
  {
    "spotlight-title": "Spotlight 1",
    "spotlight-body": "<p>This is the first spotlight</p>"
  }
]
```

And in my other d8 site that i'm trying to consume the JSON output through the Feeds Migrate module I've tried setting $.* and $.[] in the JSON Item Selector and having no luck. I quickly get the error "An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 500" in the recent log messages I see "Notice: Undefined index: $.[] in Drupal\migrate_plus\…"

What am I supposed to to be setting as the Item Selector? I followed these steps to get JSON REST export from view https://internetdevels.com/blog/views-rest-export-drupal-8

Thanks!

Comment: That’s incorrect. The item selector should be the path to the item that holds those results. What’s the name of the structure containing that?

Comment: Hi Kevin, I'm not sure i understand your question. The json feed is coming from a url and the output is what i have above. That's all the view is giving me. Thanks